# CDO 1.2.1 (MAPI) html message

Tags: html, mapi

I'm developing a C# application that interacts with exchange to send emails.
To do that I use CDO 1.2.1 (MAPI) to log into exchange and create the message.
The problem is that I need to send a message with HTML body and it seems that is impossible to do this without using the Outlook interop.

Any way to send an HTML message using CDO 1.2.1 (MAPI) without using the Outlook Interop?

Answer (score 0):

Set the PR_)HTML (0x10130102) property using Message.Fields.
Note that the property is binary (PT_BINARY), so you'd need to convert your HTML data to a hex string first.